# Shortcuts to label files in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

> Are there any shortcuts to label a file in Finder?

The fastest way i know is **to place an icon in the menubar**, but it would be much better when i can do it with the keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make your owns, creating an *Application* with **Automator** and then assigning a **Shortcut** to it.

To create the *Aplication* just:

1. Go to **/Aplications/Automator** and create a new **Work Flow**.
2. Select **Get Selected Finder Items**.
3. Then select **Label Finder Items**, and choose the color you want to label with.
4. Save as *Aplication*.

Now, you could assign a shortcut to it with an application such as [QuickSilver](http://download.cnet.com/Quicksilver/3000-2344_4-10281138.html?tag=mncol;1), for instance.

You could, too, create a **Service** in **Automator**, which, as [Daniel](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9388/daniel-lawson) points out, can get a shortcut assigned directly. [This](http://blog.fosketts.net/2010/08/09/assign-keyboard-shortcut-applescript-automator-service/) post, shows you how.

Comment: Or you could create a **Service** in Automator, which can then be assigned a shortcut directly.

Comment: @DanielLawson Indeed. Thats covered in the post I link to. Perhaps I should have made that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I had assigned shortcuts to scripts like this in [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/), but I stopped using them because [getting the selection does not work reliably in 10.7 or 10.8](http://openradar.appspot.com/9406282).

```
try
    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with f in items of (get selection as alias list)
            try
                set label index of f to item 1 of {2, 1, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7}
            end try
        end repeat
    end tell
end try
```

Comment: I tried this method but it only labels the color red, how can you cycle through the other labels ?

Comment: You have to save different scripts for each color (1 is orange, 3 is yellow, 0 is none). But they aren't really usable until Apple fixes that bug.

Comment: What is the bug exactly ?

Comment: If you open a new Finder window and select some files, `tell app "Finder" to selection` refers to the second frontmost window (or desktop). It doesn't happen if you move focus to some other application and back first.