# Can you color label a file/folder in Finder using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, macbook-pro

Is there a faster way to label a selected file or folder without having to right-click and choosing a colour ? Such as a keyboard shortcut or another method to do this ?

Comment: Take a look here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55064/shortcuts-to-label-files-in-finder